# как соединить эти таблицы и вычислить sum

Tags: sql, oracle

У меня есть 2 таблицы
select * from cars;

```
    ID        COM ENAME    COUNTRY              SAL
```

---

```
     1 MERCEDES   A200      USA            39958
     2 MERCEDES   C200      USA            44417
     3 MERCEDES   E300      USA            50828
     4 MERCEDES   GLE63S    USA           158828
```

select * from sets;

```
    ID        COM ENAME                  SAL
```

---

```
     1          1 COMFORT                  0
                2 PROGRESSIVE           5000
                3 SPORT                 6200
                4 STYLE                 2800
```

я хочу join
 select
from cars id_1, ename_MERCEDES,MODEL_A200,sel_39958
join on sets table, тот который SAL цена будет вот такой
нужен мне ответ, как я могу это сделать ?

```
ID_1      ENAME  COM    COUNTRY              SAL
```

---

```
     1 MERCEDES   A200      USA            39 958
     2 MERCEDES   A200      USA            44 598
     3 MERCEDES   A200      USA            46 158
     4 MERCEDES   A200      USA            42 758
```

Comment: Исходные данные более-менее ясны, поправьте только шапки, чтобы имена колонок чётко соответствовали данным. А вот как получен такой результат из показанных данных - неясно совершенно. Объясняйте, по каждой строке результата, особенно по второй - ну не бьётся сумма, хоть застрелись.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, требуется тупое

```
SELECT sets.com, cars.ename, cars.model, cars.contry, cars.sal+sets.sal sal
FROM cars, sets
WHERE cars.id = 1
```

?